# How to make a this output in a string in django?

Tags: python, django

I am working in a django project where my requirement is to create a string from this output
**[{'Jira_Column': 'Epic', 'RelationalOperators': '=', 'Jira_Value': 'DevOps', 'LogicalOperator': ''}, {'Jira_Column': 'Sprint', 'RelationalOperators': '=', 'Jira_Value': 'DX4C Sprint 18 (FY21-Q4)', 'LogicalOperator': 'AND'}]**

my string should be only the values not the column names
string should be like this from the output I shared: **Epic = Devops AND Sprint = DX4C Sprint 18 (FY21-Q4)**
Here's my view

```
def rule_assignment(request):
    print("check")
    rules = list(assignmentRule.objects.values_list('id','Developer','Epic'))
    print(rules)
    for rule in rules:
        assignmentRules = list(assignmentRuleItem.objects.values('Jira_Column', 'RelationalOperators', 'Jira_Value', 'LogicalOperator').filter(Rule_No = rule[0]))
        print(assignmentRules)
        
    return render (request, 'hello/Dependency_Management.html')
```

And here are my models

```
class developer(models.Model):  
    Developer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Expertise = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Availability_Hours = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Developer_Name

class assignmentRule(models.Model): 
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Developer = models.ForeignKey(developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Epic = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id

class assignmentRuleItem(models.Model): 
    Jira_Column = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    RelationalOperators= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Jira_Value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    LogicalOperator = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    Rule_No = models.ForeignKey(assignmentRule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

can someone please help me to create that string like I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

I mean if you are only wanting to print this and not pass it to the view you can use an fstring.
Assuming that your assignment rules query contains the following options:

```
{'Jira_Column': 'Epic', 'RelationalOperators': '=', 'Jira_Value': 'DevOps', 'LogicalOperator': ''}, {'Jira_Column': 'Sprint', 'RelationalOperators': '=', 'Jira_Value': 'DX4C Sprint 18 (FY21-Q4)', 'LogicalOperator': 'AND'}

    # This is not reusable code but meets your requirement
     assignmentRules = assignmentRuleItem.objects.values('Jira_Column', 'RelationalOperators', 'Jira_Value', 'LogicalOperator').filter(Rule_No = rule[0])
     ar = assignmentRules
     print(f"{ar[0].Jira_Column} {ar[0].RelationalOperators} {ar[0].Jira_Value} {ar[1].LogicalOperator} {ar[1].Jira_Column} {ar[1].RelationalOperators} {ar[1].Jira_Value}")
```

I do think though that this question isn't really in the guidelines of SO. But I believe this code would work in this very specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is that simple what you need - why not just loop through your list of dict?

```
for item in assignmentRules:
   mystring += item["LogicalOperator"] + " " + item['Jira_Column'] + "=" + item['Jira_Value'] + " "
```